# Vertical tree structure orientation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create organizational chart in vertical orientation, I found  nice example [**here**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), this example is based on horizontal tree and I tried to change it vertical orientation, it shows the link between nodes vertically but keeps showing node circles horizontally.

For vertical orientation, I use [**this example**](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/8326869)  and [**this one**](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html)

I have setup a clean [**Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGVxvj?editors=1010) for this hopeing to get some help and make it work

---

#### My code

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Which is not version properly."

Comment: @Cyril, It was not meant to be there i have removed it, actually it should be `Which is not showing vertically properly.`

Comment: ok,, if i am talking about this example what is not coming properly http://plnkr.co/edit/fUdxVNFC9KtTuKRudoP1?p=preview

Comment: @Cyril, This example is fine but when i try to modify my code based on this example it breaks as i want only two nodes to be open & rest should open as user click on them... in Vertical orientation

Answer (score 3):

Well i didn't do much just merged the two examples:

1) [example1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) {collapsible horizontal node}

2) [example2](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/8326869) {vertical layout}

So vertical layout you need to define the projection as:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x, d.y];//for vertical layout
  });
```

Instead of

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });//for horizontal layout
```

Placing nodes:

```
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";//vertical layout
    })
    .on("click", click);
```

Instead of

```
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })//horizaontal layout
      .on("click", click);
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qddPfqeKOHJrg6Uj0m00?p=preview)

Hope this helps