# Rotate tree diagram on d3.js v5 (from horizental to vertical)

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have the initial state of tree diagram that I'm building, with collapse animation and custom node design but whatever I try to make the tree vertical instead of horizontal I mess something else (animation not working well, the lines are wrong and other problems).

I'm trying to visualize a merkle tree where a vertical display is more intuitive. unfortunately I dont have strong background in front-end or deep understanding of d3 lib.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .node rect {
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        fill: #fff;
    }
    
    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "NODE NAME 1",  
    "subname": "CODE N1",    
    "fill":"orange",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "subname": "CODE N1",    
        "fill":"blue"
      },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.2","subname": "CODE N1"  ,"fill":"blue" },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.3","subname": "CODE N1","fill":"blue",
      "children": [
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.3","fill":"blue","subname": "CODE N1",
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.1","subname": "CODE N1",
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ] },
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.4","fill":"blue", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.2", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ]
           }
        ]
        }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

    var rectHeight = 60, rectWidth = 120;
    
    nodeEnter.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("width", rectWidth)
      .attr("height", rectHeight)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (rectHeight/2)*-1)
      .attr("rx","5")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.data.fill;
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", "-.35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("dy", "1.75em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.subname; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three changes below from your code show that the flip from horizontal to vertical orientation is based on the `transform` attribute of the nodes during enter and update, and the drawing of the links.

You can see that because the changes put x and y in the normal order, that the natural orientation is vertical - but many examples of D3 trees out there have horizontal orientations.

There's a few other questions that address this e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099430/how-to-change-orientation-of-a-d3-tree-layout-by-90-degrees), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474428/vertical-tree-structure-orientation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444293/how-to-get-the-vertically-oriented-tree-using-d3-js). As they are a few years old this post shows a D3 v5 example of the general principle.

Change 1 - note the change flips x and y:

```
  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        // BEFORE ....
        //return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        // AFTER ....
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);
```

Change 2 - note the change flips x and y:

```
  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        // BEFORE ....
        //return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        // AFTER ....
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });
```

And, Change 3 - same x and y flip plus `(rectWidth / 2)` draws the links centered in the nodes.

```
  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    // BEFORE ....
    //path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
    //        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
    //          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
    //          ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    // AFTER ....
    path = `M ${s.x + (rectWidth / 2)} ${s.y}
            C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2 + (rectWidth / 2)} ${s.y},
              ${(s.x + d.x) / 2 + (rectWidth / 2)} ${d.y},
              ${d.x + (rectWidth / 2)} ${d.y}`
              
    return path
  }
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .node rect {
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        fill: #fff;
    }
    
    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "NODE NAME 1",  
    "subname": "CODE N1",    
    "fill":"orange",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "subname": "CODE N1",    
        "fill":"blue"
      },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.2","subname": "CODE N1"  ,"fill":"blue" },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.3","subname": "CODE N1","fill":"blue",
      "children": [
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.3","fill":"blue","subname": "CODE N1",
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.1","subname": "CODE N1",
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ] },
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.4","fill":"blue", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.2", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ]
           }
        ]
        }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180}); 

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        // BEFORE ....
        //return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        // AFTER ....
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

    var rectHeight = 60, rectWidth = 120;
    
    nodeEnter.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("width", rectWidth)
      .attr("height", rectHeight)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (rectHeight/2)*-1)
      .attr("rx","5")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.data.fill;
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", "-.35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("dy", "1.75em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.subname; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        // BEFORE ....
        //return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        // AFTER ....
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          // BEFORE ....
          //return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
          // AFTER ....
          return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    // BEFORE ....
    //path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
    //        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
    //          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
    //          ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    // AFTER ....
    path = `M ${s.x + (rectWidth / 2)} ${s.y}
            C ${(s.x + d.x) / 2 + (rectWidth / 2)} ${s.y},
              ${(s.x + d.x) / 2 + (rectWidth / 2)} ${d.y},
              ${d.x + (rectWidth / 2)} ${d.y}`
              
    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats progress :) but the collapse animation is still off, here I captured my screen so you can see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h21OxzPRR5N3UOK_gTFScgUQfnoG0rwB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The structure of your tree in the video is not the same as the tree in the question. I think the example I posted addresses the underlying issue in your code i.e. the switch from horizontal to vertical is based on the switching x/y in the transforms and diagonal function. Read the other answers I linked to if you're not clear about this.